# Capturar teclas pressionadas mesmo sendo pressionadas fora do app

Tags: c#, winforms

bom dia

Eu fiz um programinha aonde ele mostra a tecla digitada , é algo bem simples , apenas para eu aprender o uso do Windows form application.
Meu objetivo era que ao rodar outro app , por exemplo o word , ele aparecesse encima as teclas que iam sendo digitadas , mas ao abrir outra janela ele para de capturar.
obs: é minha primeira/segunda vez fazendo um post , perdão se ficou malfeito.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace prj1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            lbl1.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        }

        private void bnt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Existem questões de segurança envolvidas nesse caso... O que você descreve é um KeyLogger... por que você quer capturar a digitação fora da sua aplicação?

Comment: Pois um amigo meu faz live na twitch , e ele quebrou a web cam , e para não ficar um espaço aberto , ele queria algo que mostrasse o que ele está teclando e clicando no mouse , eu achei programas na internet que fazem isso tranquilamente , mas queria aprender

Answer (score 0):

Vi [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962931/getasynckeystate-and-using-system-windows-forms-doesnt-work) um codigo que você pode tentar.

Utilizando a dll User32 combinado com um Timer em seu Form, você pode ficar verificando as teclas que forem sendo pressionadas.

Não sei se seria a melhor forma a ser utilizada, mas eu testei e funcionou muito bem.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Int16 GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            for (int key = 0; key < 255; key++)
            {
                //caso seja diferente da tecla pressionada, irá retornar zero
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767)
                {
                    char keyPress = Convert.ToChar(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```